# Active Directory Import (UPS) not updating users

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, 2019

I'm importing users with Active Directory Import (in User Profile Service) in Sharepoint Server 2019. It imports new accounts well but does not update current users. There are no errors in ULS logs. A full user import takes 2 seconds. None of the current users job titles are being updated. Anything else I can check?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate to make sure 'Replicate directory changes' permission is in place for configuration objects in active directory. If the job title alone is issue then check the mapping under 'Manage user properties' for Job title. If the mapping is correct then you can enable Verboseex ULS logs to understand if this particular property is being pulled from AD or not. These kind of issues generally does not give any error message in ULS Logs. You would need to validate property specific to understand if this property alone has issue or are there any other properties also has similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your configuration as the complete step by step in the following blog, it also works in SharePoint 2019:
[Step by Step: Active Directory Import for SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meacoex/2013/08/04/step-by-step-active-directory-import-for-sharepoint-2013/)